# How to create offline documentation for julia

Tags: documentation-generation, julia

How do you create a local version of the documentation for julia?  I tried:

```
/Applications/Julia-0.3.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/doc make html
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
make: [juliadoc-pkg] Error 128 (ignored)
PYTHONPATH=:juliadoc sphinx-build -b html -d _build/doctrees   . _build/html
Running Sphinx v1.3b1

Extension error:
Could not import extension juliadoc.jldoctest (exception: cannot import name bytes)
make: *** [html] Error 1
/Applications/Julia-0.3.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/doc
```

While sphinx appears to work it looks like I am missing some extension?  Anybody can help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Julia v0.4 onwards the documentation-system is inline, and can be generated using the Documenter.jl package. The inline doc strings placed right above the the functions, types, macros, modules and other objects is interpreted as documenting the accompanying object. An example for a function `get_coeff()` is shown below,

```
""" 
    get_coeff(a, v)
Return the coefficient of `a::TaylorN`, specified by
`v::Array{Int,1}` which has the indices of the specific monomial.
"""
function get_coeff(a::TaylorN, v::Array{Int,1})
```

Further details on the documenting can be found [here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/documentation/).

The next step is the document generation, for which Documenter.jl package is used. The detailed steps are explained [here](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/guide/index.html), as explained the output can either be obtained as markdown or html. If a pdf is required I would use pandocs to convert the .md files to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

It might be required to build the documentation from a clone of the Julia git repository and not from an archive of the Julia source. This is simple to get by having git installed and doing:

```
git clone https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia.git
```

The following snippet recreated the Julia documentation on my machine:

```
cd doc # change into the doc directory of the julia repository
make latex SPHINXOPTS="-n"
make latexpdf
# view the newly created PDF using linux default PDF viewer
evince _build/latex/JuliaLanguage.pdf
```

(after a few Enter keys pressed to ignore problems with LaTeX font issues, but it the doc turned out ok)

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, this also runs into an error message.  However, that might have to do with my local setup.

Answer (score 0):

Note that now `Documenter.jl` supports outputting pdf via LaTeX directly.

```
Pkg.add(DocumenterLaTeX)
using DocumenterLaTeX
makedocs(
    format = LaTeX(),
    ...
)
```

See [the documentation](https://juliadocs.github.io/Documenter.jl/stable/man/other-formats/#PDF-Output-via-LaTeX-1):

Comment: it should be `format = LaTeX()` and not `format = LaTeX`